# Converting Part into String

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

```
package servlet;


import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;



import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.security.Security;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession; 
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

import database.DBAO;
import model.Login;



  /**
  * Servlet implementation class SignupServlet
  */
 @MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*2, // 2MB
 maxFileSize=1024*1024*10,      // 10MB
 maxRequestSize=1024*1024*50)
 @WebServlet("/SignupServlet")
 public class SignupServlet extends HttpServlet{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private static final String SAVE_DIR="images";
   /**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */

public SignupServlet() {
    super();    
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {   
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String savePath = "C:" + File.separator + SAVE_DIR;
        File fileSaveDir=new File(savePath);
        if(!fileSaveDir.exists()){
              fileSaveDir.mkdir();
          }



        Random rand = new Random();
        int num = rand.nextInt(900000) + 100000;
        String Password = Integer.toString(num);

        String Name = request.getParameter("name");
        String Email = request.getParameter("email");
        String UserType = request.getParameter("usertype");
        String strDOB = request.getParameter("dob");
        String Gender = request.getParameter("gender");
        Part part = request.getPart("file");
        String fileName = part.toString();

        String filePath = savePath + File.separator + fileName;
        part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);



        java.sql.Date d;

        SimpleDateFormat sdf;
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        java.util.Date d2 = null;

        try{
            d2 = sdf.parse(strDOB);
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        d = new java.sql.Date(d2.getTime());

        DBAO dbao = null;
        Login login = null;




        try {      


            // configuration for mail
            Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
                String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                String port = "465";
                String fromEmail = "lookeverybodysg@gmail.com";
                String username = "lookeverybodysg";
                String password = "catdog1234";

                props.put("mail.smtp.user", fromEmail);
                props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
                props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");


                Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("lookeverybodysg", "catdog1234"); // username and password
                    }
                });
                mailSession.setDebug(true);

                Message mailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);


            dbao = new DBAO();

                if (dbao.emailExists(Email)){
                    request.setAttribute("Name", Name);
                    request.setAttribute("Email", Email);
                    request.setAttribute("UserType", UserType);
                    request.setAttribute("strDOB", strDOB);
                    request.setAttribute("Gender", Gender);
                    request.setAttribute("Pic", filePath);


                    response.setContentType("text/html");
                    out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">"); 
                    out.println("alert('The email you have used has already been regietered.');");
                    out.println("location='Login.jsp#signup';");
                    out.println("</script>"); 
                    return;
                }else{
                    login = new Login();
                    login.setName(Name);
                    login.setEmail(Email);
                    login.setPassword(Password);
                    login.setUserType(UserType);
                    login.setDOB(d);
                    login.setGender(Gender);
                    login.setPic(filePath);

                    boolean isUserSaved = dbao.saveNewUser(login);

                if (isUserSaved){
                    mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("lookeverybodysg@gmail.com"));
                    mailMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(Email));
                    mailMessage.setSubject("Thank You for signing up to LookEveryBody!");
                    mailMessage.setContent("Email :" + Email + "<br> Password :" + Password, "text/html");

                    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtps");
                    transport.connect (host, 465, username, password);

                    transport.send(mailMessage);

                    response.setContentType("text/html");
                    out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">"); 
                    out.println("alert('Your accout has been successfully created, please go to your email to get your password.');");
                    out.println("location='Login.jsp';");
                    out.println("</script>"); 
                    return;
                }

            }

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

I am able to store the path into MySQL but the name image file is weird, example is in the link:[SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH4Es.png)

I understand that the error is particular at lines:

```
Part part = request.getPart("file");
String fileName = part.toString();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as i am now currently having my final year project.

Comment: Add only code relevant for the question. Try to make the code short.

Answer (score 0):

The fileName is weird because of `toString()` method in the `Part` class. This class uses default implementation from `Object` class which prints jvm-specific instance ID.

Probably your Part class implementation has public methods which return file name. Try this:

```
String fileName = part.getSubmittedFileName(();
```

Instead of:

```
String fileName = part.toString();
```

Optionally you can allways get human-readable `fileName` introducing additional attribute into `request`.

Also **consider** generating file names by yourself - getting random `UUID` as a `fileName` for example. UUID file name generation would help to prevent names clashes in the file system (what if user would submit two different files with identical names?)

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the error by adding this code:

```
   private String extractFileName(Part part) {
    String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");
    for (String s : items) {
        if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length()-1);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

However if i want to host this webapplication how do i change the path so that it is store in the web-content folder in my Web Project.

Comment: I managed to store it in the web-content folder, however now i want to display the image on the browser, so what should i do?

Comment: Read above link for why you shouldn't do that and the link therein how you can serve back it.